# OpenCV: The linked framework 'opencv2.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, opencv

I am using OpenCV library on one of my macOS project using Swift programming language and Xcode IDE.

I am able to compile OpenCV by following below instructions,

1. Prepare CMake. (e.g. `brew install cmake`)
2. Download `opencv-4.2.0.zip` from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.2.0.zip.
3. Prepare a working directory. (e.g. `mkdir ~/foo`)
4. Unpack the file into the working directory.
5. Open terminal at the working directory. (e.g. `cd ~/foo`)
6. Run a build script by python 2. `python opencv-4.2.0/platforms/osx/build_framework.py osx`
7. Copy `osx/opencv2.framework` into `OpenCVSample_macOS` directory.

It's working great in my macOS project. But I have to archive the build for distribution. When I am going to archive I am getting the error,

> The linked framework 'opencv2.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64.

The same error I got for dlib & I [requested help on issues.](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/2479)

[image]

But I get to use dlib library for building macOS app for Intel processor by setting Excluded architecture as arm64.

[image]

Luckily I found a [this git repo](https://github.com/ura14h/OpenCVSample) for building OpenCV for osx. But I  don't have any idea to build the OpenCV for macOS along with M1 Chip support. Can you please anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is opencv2.framework built only for Intel or is it build for m1 too?